# Regex.Matches find least amount of characters per each match found

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

I want to iterate over each match but my code only finds 1 match by getting everything between the first and last character to find in the pattern.

Basically, I want to iterate over the 3 matches found in the following string:

```
value = "{account_id}{user_id}{someValue}";
```

Value could include any number of these "{str}" substrings where str is upper or lower case characters and can contain `_`.

But it only finds 1 match (the whole thing) using the following pattern: `"{\\S+}"`

```cs
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(value, "{\\S+}"))
{
    var key = match.Value.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "").Trim();
    // do stuff with key...
}
```

This makes sense because "{" and "}" are both non-white space character so I tried using `"{[a-zA-Z_]}"` but this fails too.

```cs
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(value, "{[a-zA-Z_]}"))
{
    var key = match.Value.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "").Trim();
    // do stuff with key...
}
```

Variable key in the loop should be "account_id", then "user_id", then "someValue", however it is always "account_iduser_idsomeValue (the whole thing).

How can I fix this?

EDIT: I just tried adding `*` to the end of the pattern but it only returns 2 matches (an empty set and the whole thing again). Using `+` instead will return just 1 result (the whole thing and not the empty set) which is no different.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not accounting for multiple occurrences of { } in the text to search. Add quantifiers to your regex like `"({\\w})*"` and you should be good to go with multiple captures.

Switch * for + if there will always be at least 1 match.

Comment: Thanks. I just added a screenshot to the question as i tried this but it only returned an empty set and the whole thing again.

Comment: It should work now, there was mistake in my suggestion.

Comment: Hmm, that seems to return 33 results of empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using `({[a-zA-Z_]+})` as my pattern. It took many guesses and tweaking to figure this out.